# How to fix mysql query syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning some PHP/MYSQL over a tutorial and I think that syntax has changed since that tutorial was produced. Please help me out, this are my first steps with PHP/MYSQL. I have been stuck here for some hours now. Connection to DB is successful, but can't query any data.

I run local wamp server and here is the code:
PHP 5.4
MYSQL 5.6

Here is the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table' at line 1

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'connect.php';
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table") or die($db->error);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Is your table really called table? If it is, you'll need to escape it with backticks; as TABLE is a reserved word.

Comment: To "close" the question properly, click the white checkmark next to an answer below until it turns green. That's how she rolls 'round here ;-) and welcome to StackOverflow. (Merry Xmas) ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `table` is the name of your table then you need to escape it with back ticks:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table`") or die($db->error);
```

This is because `table` is one of [MySQL reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and the rule is that if you need to use them then they need to be escaped with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `table`") or die($db->error);
$result = $db->fetch_array("SELECT * FROM `table`") or die($db->error);

print_r($result);
```

You are just selecting it. You need to fetch it as an array.

Also as @vee noticed, you need to use backticks => `` ` `` around the word table because `table` is a [**MySQL reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Thank you soo much.Indeed, the problem was with the table name = "table". Kudoz to you all for fast and helpful answers.